# Strong polynomial time algorithm for deciding LP feasibility

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, polynomial-time

Let
$$A \cdot X + B \preceq 0$$ be a system of linear inequalities with $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^m$ where $m \geq n$. According to Farkas lemma, exactly one of the following two is true:

1. $\exists X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A\cdot X + B \preceq 0$
2. $\exists y \in \mathbb{R}^m_+$ such that $y^T \cdot A = 0$ and $y^T \cdot B > 0$

Then lets define the convex optimization problem:
$$ d^{\star} = \min q^T \cdot A \cdot A^T \cdot q \\ s.t \begin{cases} q \succeq 0\\ B^T \cdot q > 0\\ \| q\| \leq 1 \end{cases}$$  Let $q^{\star}$ be the solution to the above problem.

We have two possible outcomes:

a) $d^{\star} = 0$ hence $q^{\star} \cdot A = 0$, $B^T \cdot q^{\star} > 0$ therefore the system is NOT feasible

b) $d^{\star} > 0$ hence $\not \exists q \succeq 0$ with $q^T \cdot B > 0$ and $q^T \cdot A = 0$ otherwise  $\frac{q}{\| q \|}$ would vanish the above function, therefore yielding a smaller value than $d^{\star}$. It follows that the linear system HAS a solution

### Question

The above optimization problem can be solved with ellipsoid algorithm without dependency on the problem data, right? Of course, this does not yield the solution (to LP) but can decide if the LP is feasible or not, in polynomial complexity for real coefficients LP ?! What am I missing ?

### Update

In the above optimization problem we have $B^T\cdot q > 0$ generating an open set. It is obviously, not possible to ask just $B^T \cdot q \geq 0$ since this would automatically generate the trivial solution $q = 0$. Instead, I think that
$$ d^{\star} = \min q^T \cdot A \cdot A^T \cdot q \\ 
s.t \begin{cases} q \succeq 0\\ B^T \cdot q \geq 0 \\ \textbf{1}^T \cdot q \geq 1\\ \|q\| \leq \sqrt{m} \end{cases}$$ should solve some of the complaints. This prevents the solution $q = 0$ and has closed contraints set. However, here take $\frac{q}{1^T \cdot q}$ instead of $\frac{q}{\|q\|}$ in the interpretation of $d^{\star} > 0$. Am I missing something ?

Comment: 1) If $B = 0$ the LP is trivial $X = 0$ is a solution, so I am assuming $\| B \| > 0$  Further more I think non-feasibility of the system of constraints (regarding $q$) will have the same consequence: the LP is feasible

Comment: We usually only deal with *closed* constraints, but $B^T \cdot q > 0$ isn't.

Comment: @yuvalFilmus can you please expand on that? The constrained set should be closed, alright! But, that will not matter if the solution will not be on the frontier of the constrained set. Furthermore, will asking $B^T \cdot q > \epsilon$ help?

Comment: How small is $\epsilon$?

Comment: Well I am thinking, that if $\exists q_0^T \cdot A = 0$ and $q_0^T \cdot B > 0$ follows that $ \epsilon < q_0^T \cdot B$, which of course will make $\epsilon$ dependent of the problem data! That is the reason for which I ask for strict inequality ...

Comment: Isn't  an optimization algorithm able to handle such a constraint ?

Comment: @yuvalFilmus thank you for your comments! I have proposed a fix to your critique ... can you check again?

Comment: The matrices $A,B$ are still part of the instance. What is gained by considering your problem instead of the original one? You can use the ellipsoid algorithm to solve the original problem just as well.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus What I am saying is that although A,B appear somewhere around here, the number of flops required by ellipsoid algorithm does not depend on them. Indeed the initial radius for the algorithm is $1$ in my first problem, and $\sqrt{m}$ is sufficient for the second. Other that that are just computations, which have the same complexity whatever A, B! right ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the speed of convergence of the ellipsoid algorithm for non-linear objective functions.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I think that up to the complexity of the oracle, it has the same rate of decreasing the volume as for the linear case. It has basically the same iterations: cut the ellipsoid through its center to obtain a smaller volume one. The ellipsoid algorithm was actually developed to solve convex (not necessarily linear) optimization problems in the first place

Comment: The constraint $\|q\| \leq \sqrt{m}$ (whose need is unclear to me) is not linear. Is that an issue?

Comment: I think not since it is convex. I added it to make sure that the constraint set is bounded. It can probably be replaced by something like $1^T \cdot q < 2$ for that matter. As a matter of fact I think that the ellipsoid can be initialized with the ball/ellipsoid $B(0, \sqrt{m})$, whatever A,B.